# Trying to understand a mod_rewrite script

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Could someone explain how the mod_rewrite script below works?
The goal is to catch an access to probe.com that has nothing following it and redirect that to probewebsites.com.  If the access is to probe.com/anything, such as probe.com/register.php, the access stays at probe.com, accessing, in  this case,  probe.com/register.php.

The script works, I'm just not sure how.

I see that line 2 looks for an access to probe.com.
Then line 3 somehow verifies that nothing is following probe.com.
Line 4 looks like it's collecting a backreference, but it's never used. 
Thanks for any help.

```
1. RewriteEngine on
2. RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} probe\.com [NC]
3. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
4. Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://probewebsites.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general understanding about the rules is correct. Let me expand on that.

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Turns the mod-rewrite rules processing on for this directory.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} probe.com [NC]
```

Looks like it's looking for `probe.com` but it's not. Since it's a regex pattern, `.` would match any character. So, `probeXcom` would also pass; and since no regex boundaries (`^`, `$`) have been specified, it becomes a sub-string match. That means `csi.probe.com` or `probe.com.uk` would also match. The correct pattern to match only `probe.com` or `www.probe.com` would be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?probe\.com$ [NC]
```

`^` and `$` match on the start and end boundaries of the `%{HTTP_HOST}` which refers to the HTTP header by the same name. `\.` escapes the regex's match-on-any-character `.` and starts matching on the literal dot `.` character now. The question mark in `(www\.)?` makes the captured `www.` optional. Finally, `[NC]` stands for *no case* and makes the test case-insensitive.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
```

This condition is actually not required because you can make the same match in the `RewriteRule` itself. So, the new rule should look like

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://probewebsites.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Notice, it's not `^/$` and it's not a typo. The `RewriteRule` pattern matches the directory path but doesn't include the leading `/` as in `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

`[L]` marks the rule as *last* since we're redirecting anyway which is specified by `[R=301]`. The status code `301` indicates to the browser that this redirect is permanent and so the browser will cache it. If you specify just `[R]`, the server would do a `302` *temporarily moved* redirect.

So, your final .htacces should look like

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?probe\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://probewebsites.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: quick question on this line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?probe\.com$ [NC]`  You are not using the exp `(www\.)` as a backreference, so is the purpose of the `()` here just to group the `www\.` so  the `?` applies to the  `www\.` segment? Also , is there a way of grouping `www\.` without using `()` i.e. if you explicitly did not want the segment to be picked up as a back reference?

Comment: Good question. Yes, it's purpose is to group that sequence of chars so that the following `?` makes it optional but as a side-effect it gets picked up as a back-ref as well. If you don't want to pick it up as a back-reference, start the group as `(?:www\.)?`. The `?:` char sequence at the start makes it a un-referred group now.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  But if the request that came in were  probe.com/register.php, how would this fail the condition so that it doesn't get redirected to probewebsites.com/register.php?

Comment: If  a request were to come for probe.com/register.php, `%{REQUEST_URI}` would contain `/register.php` and `RewriteRule` would match on `^register\.php$` (no leading / like I said before). Hence, our rule which matches on `^$` (i.e. no path info at all) would fail and prevent the redirection.